# Python : why a method from super class not seen?

Tags: python, class, logging, twisted

i am trying to implement my own version of a `DailyLogFile`

```
from twisted.python.logfile import DailyLogFile

class NDailyLogFile(DailyLogFile):

     def __init__(self, name, directory, rotateAfterN = 1, defaultMode=None):
         DailyLogFile.__init__(self, name, directory, defaultMode)   # why do not use super. here? lisibility maybe?
         #
         self.rotateAfterN = rotateAfterN

    def shouldRotate(self):
         """Rotate when N days have passed since file creation"""
         delta = datetime.date(*self.toDate()) - datetime.date(*self.toDate(self.createdOn)) 
         return delta > datetime.timedelta(self.rotateAfterN)

    def __getstate__(self):
        state = BaseLogFile.__getstate__(self)
        del state["rotateAfterN"]
        return state

threadable.synchronize(NDailyLogFile)
```

but it looks like i miss a fundamental of Python subclassing process...as i get this error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/twistedtestproxy04.py", line 88, in <module>
    import ndailylogfile
  File "/home/ndailylogfile.py", line 56, in <module>
    threadable.synchronize(NDailyLogFile)
  File "/home/lt/mpv0/lib/python2.6/site-packages/twisted/python/threadable.py", line 71, in synchronize
    sync = _sync(klass, klass.__dict__[methodName])
KeyError: 'write'
```

so i need to explicitly add and define others methods like `Write` and `rotate` method like this:

```
class NDailyLogFile(DailyLogFile):
     [...]
     def write(self, data): # why must i add these ?
         DailyLogFile.write(self, data)

     def rotate(self): # as we do nothing more than calling the method from the base class!
            DailyLogFile.rotate(self)

threadable.synchronize(NDailyLogFile)
```

while i thought it would be correctly inherit from the base mother class. Notice that i do nothing, only calling "super",

please can someone explain why i am wrong on my first idea that it was not necessary to add the Write method?

is there a way to say to Python inside my NDailyLogFile that it shoud have all the methods DailyLogFile that are not defined directly from its mother class? So that it prevents this king of error  `_sync(klass, klass.__dict__[methodName]` and that avoid to specify excplicitly ?

( original code of DailyLogFile that inspired me it taken from the twisted source here https://github.com/tzuryby/freespeech/blob/master/twisted/python/logfile.py )

EDIT: about using `super`, i get:

```
  File "/home/lt/inwork/ndailylogfile.py", line 57, in write
    super.write(self, data)
exceptions.AttributeError: type object 'super' has no attribute 'write'
```

so will not use it. My thoughs was it was right... i must have definitively missed something

Comment: From OOP perspective you are doing it right, except you don't really want to override all the methods. And you should really use `super`. 

The problem is that `threadable.py` is not very friendly to that OOP stuff, as the line that throws an error checks for existence of `write` in *that particular class*, but not it's ancestors. I have no experience with `twisted` so don't know how to overcome this. Maybe there are some guides on that somewhere on the internet?

Comment: ok, thank you for the comment. I do not know if there is a better answer for now. but you have provide a good part :)

Comment: I think the silly and probably wrong way to achieve what are you  trying to do is to replace that `klass.__dict__[methodName]` with `getattr(klass, methodname)` in `threadable.py`. And most likely it won't work. And it's a patch to twisted. And it probably breaks something outside that particular use case. So, please try it as a proof of concept and if it really works - suggest as a patch to twisted via ailing lists or ticket tracker or whatever they use to leverage development. And don't forget to post something here so I would know if it helped :)

Comment: well you help me a lot and should have provided an anwser so i can accept it. I'm not going to patch `threadable.py` and will add the define has stated in my own subclass. As it is the easiest way :)

Comment: try to set `NDailyLogFile.synchronized` to include only methods that you want to be overridden and to be syncrhonized i.e., don't overwrite `write` method. I'm assuming that parent methods remain synchronized and the lock is the same.

Comment: fyi, `super.foo` doesn't work because `super` doesn't work that way. you have to do `super(NDailyLogFile, self).foo`;  buuuuut... it probably still won't work for you, because the base class you're inheriting from does not itself inherit from `object`, and so super can't be used there.

Comment: It sounds like you got some answers to the question you asked, but to answer the question you didn't ask - don't bother using `synchronized`.  The base class is already synchronized, and you didn't override `write` so there's no reason for the subclass to be synchronized.

Comment: @Jean-PaulCalderone: are you saying `shouldRotate()` (assume it is a new method) magically becomes synchronized without using `.synchronized` or new methods are never ever used from multiple threads outside `write` method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dare say that the `twisted/python/threadable.py` code has a bug in it.  `__dict__` only returns the local attributes, not the inherited attributes.  [Other](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9377819/584846) [posts](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/comp.lang.python/YcIRoggyDNM) say to use `dir()` or `inspect.getmembers()` to get them.

The good news is that you are correct on your first idea that the `write` method is inherited.  The bad news is that Twisted doesn't recognize inherited methods, so you have to write them yourself.

Comment: `dir` will return a list of stuff attributes and methods, but not the methods themselves. `inspect.getmembers` returns a list of tuples of structure (`name`, `value`), so it's possible to find a method, but harder than just using `getattr`.

Comment: so i may add them explicitly from the subclass without having to define them? i am not sure to get the point here on how i could use `dir` or `inspect.getmembers()` for this.

Comment: @user2468222 you'll have to patch `threadable.py` anyway, but do it in a more involving way than using `getattr`

Answer (score 3):

There is one workaround, just do:

```
NDailyLogFile.__dict__ = dict( NDailyLogFile.__dict__.items() + DailyLogFile.__dict__.items() )
threadable.synchronize(NDailyLogFile)
```

There is a problem here that you are using the class without having instantiated it. This workaround works because you are forcing to change the class attributes before the instantiation.

Another important comment ist that for a subclass of `DailyLogFile` the command `super` would not work, since `DailyLogFile` is a so called "old style class", or "classobj". The `super` works for the "new style" classes only. [See this question for further information about this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9698614/832621).